# External variable in the title of the chart

Tags: javascript, php, charts, highcharts, gauge

I'm working in a school project and i'm getting the data from a php file to show in the gauge.
I using this javascript code to update de chart every second:

```
    function requestData() {
    $.getJSON('values.php', function(data) {
            var new_value = data;
            var point = $('#ta').highcharts().series[0].points[0];
            point.update(new_value);
            setTimeout(requestData, 500)
            }

)
}
```

With this code i'm able to update the chart, the problem is, i need to show the numeric value too, in another part of the chart. Here is what i try:

```
  yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: '<div id="tav">'+new_value+'V</div>',
            useHTML: true,
            y: 80
        }
```

When i put "new_value" the chart stop working and i can't see nothing. If a leave the "new_value" from this part of the chart it works perfectly.

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update y-axis title you have to use the code like:

```
$('#container').highcharts().yAxis[0].update({
            title:{
                text:"My text"
            }
        });
```

I have created a wroking demo of how to **dynamically update y-axis title on button click**: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/MRxn3/)**

JS code section to dynamically update chart title on a button click:

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
$('#my_btn').click(function(){
    //alert('hey');
    chart.yAxis[0].update({
        title:{
            text:"My text"
        }
    });
    alert('Y-axis title changed to "My text" !');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `new_value` is localy defined. You could define the variable as an object's property:

```
var obj = {};
function requestData() {
$.getJSON('values.php', function(data) {
        obj.new_value = data;
        var point = $('#ta').highcharts().series[0].points[0];
        point.update(new_value);
        setTimeout(requestData, 500)
        }

)
}
```

and

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: '<div id="tav">'+obj.new_value+'V</div>',
        useHTML: true,
        y: 80
    }
```

Comment: I've tried and did not work. The gauge dot not update anymore and the new_value on the yAxis show undefined

Comment: When are you assigning the `yAxis`? Are you listening any event?

Comment: the only event is the load, that call the function requestData

Answer (score 0):

Use indeed `Axis.setTitle()` method, see:

```
 function requestData() {
     $.getJSON('values.php', function (data) {
         var new_value = data;
         var chart = $('#ta').highcharts()
         var point = chart.series[0].points[0];
         var yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];

         yAxis.setTitle({text: new_value });
         point.update(new_value);
         setTimeout(requestData, 500);
     })
 }
```

Comment: When i set yAxis as a variable, the chart stops updating and stands stuck at zero. What should i put down on the yAxis, should i left it blanc?

Comment: My bad, should be `yAxis`, not `yAXis` ;) Edited answer. Thanks!